# What's the probability of not finding a subsequence in a sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was trying to solve the following problem:

Given a sequence of n letters sampled (randomly, with possible repetitions, and equal probability) from an alphabet having v letters, what is the expected value of the fraction of all possible substrings of length 2 with 0 counts over all the possible substrings of length 2?

For example, let's say I have a word of 10 letters. On average, how many substrings/words of 2 letters will not be found in the word (over all possible words of 2 letters)?

Considering the word ABCDEFGHIJ, here we found the subsequence AB, BC, CD.. but not AC, AD, AZ and so on. My question is, on average, how many words of length 2 will not be present in a word of n letters?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't understand what you would like to compute.

Comment: An equivalent and simpler problem is to ask for the expected number of unique substrings of length 2 in a random word of $k$ letters in an alphabet of $n$ letters (alphabets have *letters,* not words BTW).

Comment: Thank you @whuber, your observation was really helpful! I'll leave here a paper that explains how to solve your simpler problem: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01184801/document (corollary 2.2). And thanks for the correction, I modified the question accordingly.